# ReSharper 8 - ReSharper_GotoNextOccurence no longer available in Visual Studio keyboard shortcut editor

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resharper, resharper-8.1

I can't find **ReSharper_GotoNextOccurence** and **ReSharper_GotoPreviousOccurence** in Visual Studio 2013 '*Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Keyboard*'.

This is one of my most used shortcuts. I use **ReSharper_HighlightUsages** and have **ReSharper_GotoNextOccurence** mapped to *Alt-Down Arrow*, but when importing my ReSharper and Visual Studio settings it is no longer hooked up and I can no longer find the commands in the shortcut editor.

Here, http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Reference__Keyboard_Shortcuts.html, you can see that ReSharper_GotoNextOccurence is the alias for go to next usage.

If anyone has any thoughts, I would appreciate it very much. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I see, action names were renamed accidentally, please try these:

- ReSharper.ReSharper_ResultList_GoToNextLocation
- ReSharper.ReSharper_ResultList_GoToPrevLocation

We will update ReSharper Web Help ASAP.